# Why eclipses are not periodic?

Tags: eclipse

From mathematics, we know that if any two or more functions are periodic in nature, their combination would also be periodic in nature with some exceptions. 
Since motions of the sun, the moon and the earth are periodic in nature, all events associated with that should also be periodic in nature (or close to periodic). It looks like they are eventually in periodic in nature except for the eclipses, why?

Comment: Have you read the [Wikipedia article on eclipse cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_cycle)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I am reading it.

Comment: [Periodicity of Solar Eclipses](https://eclipse.gsfc.nasa.gov/SEsaros/SEperiodicity.html)

Comment: I think you mean "fixed frequency" by using "periodic". The approximate fixed frerquency of the planets' trajectories  in the solar system allow to calculate the eclipse times .

Answer (score 1):

Eclipses are in fact periodic, and can be predicted accurately years into the future.